# How to pass variable to filter function within a R function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am fairly new to R. I wrote the below function which tries to summarise a dataframe, based on a feature variable (passed to the function as 'variable') and a target variable (passed to the function as `target_var`). I also pass it a value (`target_val`) on which to filter.

The function below falls over on the filter line (`filter(target_var == target_val)`). I think it has something to do with `quo`, `quosure` etc, but can't figure out how to fix it. The following code should be ready to run - if you exclude the filter line it should work, if you included the filter line it will fall over.

```
library(dplyr)
target <- c('good', 'good', 'bad', 'good', 'good', 'bad')
var_1 <- c('debit_order', 'other', 'other', 'debit_order','debit_order','debit_order')

dset <- data.frame(target, var_1)
odds_by_var <- function(dataframe, variable, target_var, target_val){

  df_name <- paste('odds', deparse(substitute(variable)), sep = "_")
  variable_string <- deparse(substitute(variable))
  target_string <- deparse(substitute(target_var))

  temp_df1 <- dataframe %>%
    group_by_(variable_string, target_string) %>%
    summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
    group_by_(variable_string) %>%
    mutate(total = sum(cnt)) %>%
    mutate(rate = cnt / total) %>%
    filter(target_var == target_val) 

  assign(df_name, temp_df1, envir=.GlobalEnv)

}

odds_by_var(dset, var_1, target, 'bad')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I assume you want to filter by target good or bad. 
In my understanding, always `filter()` before you `group_by()`, as you will possibly ommit your filter variables. I restructured your function a little:

```
    dset <- data.frame(target, var_1)
odds_by_var <- function(dataframe, variable, target_var, target_val){

  df_name <- paste('odds', deparse(substitute(variable)), sep = "_")
  variable_string <- deparse(substitute(variable))
  target_string <- deparse(substitute(target_var))

  temp_df1 <- dataframe %>%
    group_by_(variable_string, target_string) %>%
    summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
    mutate(total = sum(cnt),
           rate = cnt / total) 
names(temp_df1) <- c(variable_string,"target","cnt","total","rate" )
temp_df1 <- temp_df1[temp_df1$target == target_val,]
  assign( df_name,temp_df1, envir=.GlobalEnv)

}

odds_by_var(dset, var_1, target, "bad")
```

result:

```
> odds_var_1
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   var_1 [2]
  var_1       target   cnt total  rate
  <chr>       <chr>  <int> <int> <dbl>
1 debit_order bad        1     4  0.25
2 other       bad        1     2  0.5
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your reply. However, I'm not sure that will work as I need to work out 'cnt' and 'total' before filtering out the 'goods'. So answer I'm expecting is...

Comment: `code`var_1         cnt total  rate
  <fct>       <int> <int> <dbl>
1 debit_order     1     4  0.25
2 other           1     2  0.5`code`

Comment: Sorry I'm still trying to figure out how to format my replies correctly. I'm basically expecting the debit order count to be 1, the debit order total to be 4 and the rate to be 0.25. For 'other', it will be 1, 2 and 0.5 respectively.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply. Yes, that does do the trick now. Thanks so much, that's really useful, well done. Regards, Jon